# Using Nlog to create log file. After creating bootstrapper packages and using it to install on my machine log file is not generated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nlog

My NLog.config file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log.txt" />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Note 1: I have tested variations of this file and there are no results.

NOTE 2: Running the application through visual studio logging works properly.

My settings are

Compilation Action: Content

Copy to directory: Always copy

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: I read this but I still can not solve my problem

Comment: Try sending the internal log to c:/temp and check the content

Comment: When I run it through visual studio the file is created and it is to see where the log is done as expected.
But when I create the bootstrapper the internal buffer file is not created just like the log file.